# Como executar a mesma função de JavaScript para mais de uma div

Tags: javascript, carousel, slider, touch-events

Tenho uma carrossel de slide e preciso reproduzir esse mesmo carrossel (só que com imagens e sections diferentes) na mesma página. Irei fazer esta aplicação para um blog, então, são várias categorias que vão ter diversos posts sendo "scrolados".

O problema é que este carrossel só está funcionando na primeira `div`, ele não executa nas `div`s restantes.

Podem me dar dicas do que fazer?

Montei aqui uma estrutura simples para exemplificar o que fiz até agora:

```html
<style>
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

ul {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  list-style: none;
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.slide-wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slide {
  display: flex;
}

.slide article {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 80vw;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 20px;
}
</style>

<div class="slide-wrapper">
       <div class="slide">
        <article><img src="https://unsplash.com/photos/1U0xyCNniTs" alt=""></article>
        <article><img src="https://unsplash.com/photos/1U0xyCNniTs" alt=""></article>
        <article><img src="https://unsplash.com/photos/1U0xyCNniTs" alt=""></article>
        <article><img src="https://unsplash.com/photos/1U0xyCNniTs" alt=""></article>
        <article><img src="https://unsplash.com/photos/1U0xyCNniTs" alt=""></article>
        <article><img src="https://unsplash.com/photos/1U0xyCNniTs" alt=""></article>
       </div>
     </div>   

     <div class="slide-wrapper">
       <div class="slide">
        <article><img src="https://unsplash.com/photos/1U0xyCNniTs" alt=""></article>
        <article><img src="https://unsplash.com/photos/1U0xyCNniTs" alt=""></article>
        <article><img src="https://unsplash.com/photos/1U0xyCNniTs" alt=""></article>
        <article><img src="https://unsplash.com/photos/1U0xyCNniTs" alt=""></article>
        <article><img src="https://unsplash.com/photos/1U0xyCNniTs" alt=""></article>
        <article><img src="https://unsplash.com/photos/1U0xyCNniTs" alt=""></article>
       </div>
     </div>

    <div class="slide-wrapper">
       <div class="slide">
        <article><img src="https://unsplash.com/photos/1U0xyCNniTs" alt=""></article>
        <article><img src="https://unsplash.com/photos/1U0xyCNniTs" alt=""></article>
        <article><img src="https://unsplash.com/photos/1U0xyCNniTs" alt=""></article>
        <article><img src="https://unsplash.com/photos/1U0xyCNniTs" alt=""></article>
        <article><img src="https://unsplash.com/photos/1U0xyCNniTs" alt=""></article>
        <article><img src="https://unsplash.com/photos/1U0xyCNniTs" alt=""></article>
       </div>
     </div>

<script>
class Slide {
  constructor(slide, wrapper) {
    this.slide = document.querySelector(slide)
    this.wrapper = document.querySelector(wrapper);
    this.dist = { finalPosition: 0, startX: 0, movement: 0 }
  }

  moveSlide(distX) {
    this.dist.movePosition = distX;
    this.slide.style.transform = `translate3d(${distX}px, 0, 0)`;
  }

  updatePosition(clientX) {
    this.dist.movement = (this.dist.startX - clientX) * 1.6;
    return this.dist.finalPosition - this.dist.movement;
  }

  onStart(event) {
    let movetype;
    if (event.type === 'mousedown') {
      this.dist.startX = event.clientX;
      movetype = 'mousemove';
    } else {
      this.dist.startX = event.changedTouches[0].clientX;
      movetype = 'touchmove';
    }
    this.wrapper.addEventListener(movetype, this.onMove);
  }

  onMove(event) {
    const pointerPosition = (event.type === 'mousemove') ? event.clientX : event.changedTouches[0].clientX;
    const finalPosition = this.updatePosition(pointerPosition);
    this.moveSlide(finalPosition);
  }

  onEnd(event) {
    const movetype = (event.type === 'mouseup') ? 'mousemove' : 'touchmove';
    this.wrapper.removeEventListener(movetype, this.onMove);
    this.dist.finalPosition = this.dist.movePosition;
  }

  addSlideEvents() {
    this.wrapper.addEventListener('mousedown', this.onStart);
    this.wrapper.addEventListener('touchstart', this.onStart);
    this.wrapper.addEventListener('mouseup', this.onEnd);
    this.wrapper.addEventListener('touchend', this.onEnd);
  }

  bindEvents() {
    this.onStart = this.onStart.bind(this);
    this.onMove = this.onMove.bind(this);
    this.onEnd = this.onEnd.bind(this);
  }

  init() {
    this.bindEvents();
    this.addSlideEvents();
    return this;
  }
}


const slide = new Slide('.slide', '.slide-wrapper');
slide.init();
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Seu problema tem haver com o `document.querySelector` dentro do `constructor` da classe `Slide`. [Ele retorna apenas 1 elemento do DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), logo ele retorna somente a primeira `div`.

Você teria que usar o [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) e reescrever o código para, alem de atribuir classes ou ids distintos para cada `div`, para que cada secão responda de maneira independente aos eventos de mouse.

Ou pode resolver da maneira mais rápida, direta e gambiarrando. Adicione uma classe diferente acompanhando cada `slide-wrapper` e `slide`.

Por exemplo:

- Primeira `div`:

```
<div class="slide-wrapper first">
      <div class="slide fist">
      ....
```

- Segunda `div`:

```
<div class="slide-wrapper second">
      <div class="slide second">
      ....
```

- Terceira `div`:

```
<div class="slide-wrapper third">
      <div class="slide third">
      ....
```

e depois atribuir a instância da classe `Slide` para cada uma das `div`s:

```
const slide = new Slide('.first', '.first');
const slide2 = new Slide('.second', '.second');
const slide3 = new Slide('.third', '.third');

slide.init();
slide2.init();
slide3.init();
```

Acho uma solucão gambiarra, pois acho que o melhor seria reescrever o código, mas veja se funciona do jeito que você espera:

```js
       class Slide {
        constructor(slide, wrapper) {
          this.slide = document.querySelector(slide);
          this.wrapper = document.querySelector(wrapper);
          this.dist = { finalPosition: 0, startX: 0, movement: 0 };
        }

        moveSlide(distX) {
          this.dist.movePosition = distX;
          this.slide.style.transform = `translate3d(${distX}px, 0, 0)`;
        }

        updatePosition(clientX) {
          this.dist.movement = (this.dist.startX - clientX) * 1.6;
          return this.dist.finalPosition - this.dist.movement;
        }

        onStart(event) {
          let movetype;
          if (event.type === 'mousedown') {
            this.dist.startX = event.clientX;
            movetype = 'mousemove';
          } else {
            this.dist.startX = event.changedTouches[0].clientX;
            movetype = 'touchmove';
          }
          this.wrapper.addEventListener(movetype, this.onMove);
        }

        onMove(event) {
          const pointerPosition =
            event.type === 'mousemove'
              ? event.clientX
              : event.changedTouches[0].clientX;
          const finalPosition = this.updatePosition(pointerPosition);
          this.moveSlide(finalPosition);
        }

        onEnd(event) {
          const movetype = event.type === 'mouseup' ? 'mousemove' : 'touchmove';
          this.wrapper.removeEventListener(movetype, this.onMove);
          this.dist.finalPosition = this.dist.movePosition;
        }

        addSlideEvents() {
          this.wrapper.addEventListener('mousedown', this.onStart);
          this.wrapper.addEventListener('touchstart', this.onStart);
          this.wrapper.addEventListener('mouseup', this.onEnd);
          this.wrapper.addEventListener('touchend', this.onEnd);
        }

        bindEvents() {
          this.onStart = this.onStart.bind(this);
          this.onMove = this.onMove.bind(this);
          this.onEnd = this.onEnd.bind(this);
        }

        init() {
          this.bindEvents();
          this.addSlideEvents();
          return this;
        }
      }

      const slide = new Slide('.first', '.first');
      const slide2 = new Slide('.second', '.second');
      const slide3 = new Slide('.third', '.third');

      slide.init();
      slide2.init();
      slide3.init();
```

```css
body {
      margin: 0px;
    }

    ul {
      padding: 0px;
      margin: 0px;
      list-style: none;
    }

    img {
      display: block;
      max-width: 100%;
    }

    .slide-wrapper {
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .slide {
      display: flex;
    }

    .slide article {
      flex-shrink: 0;
      width: 80vw;
      max-width: 200px;
      margin: 0 20px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="slide-wrapper first">
      <div class="slide fist">
        <article>
          <img
            src="https://images.theconversation.com/files/350865/original/file-20200803-24-50u91u.jpg?ixlib=rb-1.1.0&q=45&auto=format&w=1200&h=675.0&fit=crop"
            alt=""
          />
        </article>
        <article>
          <img
            src="https://images.theconversation.com/files/350865/original/file-20200803-24-50u91u.jpg?ixlib=rb-1.1.0&q=45&auto=format&w=1200&h=675.0&fit=crop"
            alt=""
          />
        </article>
        <article>
          <img
            src="https://images.theconversation.com/files/350865/original/file-20200803-24-50u91u.jpg?ixlib=rb-1.1.0&q=45&auto=format&w=1200&h=675.0&fit=crop"
            alt=""
          />
        </article>
        <article>
          <img
            src="https://images.theconversation.com/files/350865/original/file-20200803-24-50u91u.jpg?ixlib=rb-1.1.0&q=45&auto=format&w=1200&h=675.0&fit=crop"
            alt=""
          />
        </article>
        <article>
          <img
            src="https://images.theconversation.com/files/350865/original/file-20200803-24-50u91u.jpg?ixlib=rb-1.1.0&q=45&auto=format&w=1200&h=675.0&fit=crop"
            alt=""
          />
        </article>
        <article>
          <img
            src="https://images.theconversation.com/files/350865/original/file-20200803-24-50u91u.jpg?ixlib=rb-1.1.0&q=45&auto=format&w=1200&h=675.0&fit=crop"
            alt=""
          />
        </article>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="slide-wrapper second">
      <div class="slide second">
        <article>
          <img
            src="https://images.theconversation.com/files/350865/original/file-20200803-24-50u91u.jpg?ixlib=rb-1.1.0&q=45&auto=format&w=1200&h=675.0&fit=crop"
            alt=""
          />
        </article>
        <article>
          <img
            src="https://images.theconversation.com/files/350865/original/file-20200803-24-50u91u.jpg?ixlib=rb-1.1.0&q=45&auto=format&w=1200&h=675.0&fit=crop"
            alt=""
          />
        </article>
        <article>
          <img
            src="https://images.theconversation.com/files/350865/original/file-20200803-24-50u91u.jpg?ixlib=rb-1.1.0&q=45&auto=format&w=1200&h=675.0&fit=crop"
            alt=""
          />
        </article>
        <article>
          <img
            src="https://images.theconversation.com/files/350865/original/file-20200803-24-50u91u.jpg?ixlib=rb-1.1.0&q=45&auto=format&w=1200&h=675.0&fit=crop"
            alt=""
          />
        </article>
        <article>
          <img
            src="https://images.theconversation.com/files/350865/original/file-20200803-24-50u91u.jpg?ixlib=rb-1.1.0&q=45&auto=format&w=1200&h=675.0&fit=crop"
            alt=""
          />
        </article>
        <article>
          <img
            src="https://images.theconversation.com/files/350865/original/file-20200803-24-50u91u.jpg?ixlib=rb-1.1.0&q=45&auto=format&w=1200&h=675.0&fit=crop"
            alt=""
          />
        </article>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="slide-wrapper third">
      <div class="slide third">
        <article>
          <img
            src="https://images.theconversation.com/files/350865/original/file-20200803-24-50u91u.jpg?ixlib=rb-1.1.0&q=45&auto=format&w=1200&h=675.0&fit=crop"
            alt=""
          />
        </article>
        <article>
          <img
            src="https://images.theconversation.com/files/350865/original/file-20200803-24-50u91u.jpg?ixlib=rb-1.1.0&q=45&auto=format&w=1200&h=675.0&fit=crop"
            alt=""
          />
        </article>
        <article>
          <img
            src="https://images.theconversation.com/files/350865/original/file-20200803-24-50u91u.jpg?ixlib=rb-1.1.0&q=45&auto=format&w=1200&h=675.0&fit=crop"
            alt=""
          />
        </article>
        <article>
          <img
            src="https://images.theconversation.com/files/350865/original/file-20200803-24-50u91u.jpg?ixlib=rb-1.1.0&q=45&auto=format&w=1200&h=675.0&fit=crop"
            alt=""
          />
        </article>
        <article>
          <img
            src="https://images.theconversation.com/files/350865/original/file-20200803-24-50u91u.jpg?ixlib=rb-1.1.0&q=45&auto=format&w=1200&h=675.0&fit=crop"
            alt=""
          />
        </article>
        <article>
          <img
            src="https://images.theconversation.com/files/350865/original/file-20200803-24-50u91u.jpg?ixlib=rb-1.1.0&q=45&auto=format&w=1200&h=675.0&fit=crop"
            alt=""
          />
        </article>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use querySelectorAll, retornara uma lista com todas os elementos que atendem a query

```
slides = [];
//retornara um nodeList...
var nodes = querySelectorAll('.slide-wrapper');
for (var i = 0, e = nodes.length; i < e; i++) {
  //passa o elemento para o construtor
  slides.push(new Slide(nodes[i]));
}
```

*obs.: você também pode converter o nodeList para array com "Array.prototype.slice.call(nodeList)" e chamar um foreach

e com uma pequena adaptação no construtor, ele está pronto para receber o elemento wrapper:

```
  constructor(slide_wrapper) {
    this.slide = slide_wrapper.querySelector('.slide');//<pega o .slide que está dentro do wrapper
    this.wrapper = slide_wrapper;//<
    this.dist = { finalPosition: 0, startX: 0, movement: 0 };
  }
```